# Optional Array in vb.net xll custom function

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am converting VBA code to a VB.net .XLL with visual studio and am having a problem with the following function,

```
    Public Shared Function WhitenWithBypassCurve(ByVal rngEp() As Double, _
                  ByVal rngRho50() As Double, _
                  ByVal rngT0() As Double, _
                  ByVal rngT1() As Double, _
                  ByVal rngSGs() As Double, _
                  Optional ByVal argMediumSplitLimitSize As Double = Nothing, _
                  Optional ByVal rngSizes() As Double = Nothing, _
                  Optional ByVal argMediumSplit As Double = Nothing _
                  ) As Object
```

Now the function will work fine as long as i have a range in the rngsizes() term but will not even step into the function if this term is not included. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean it wont step into it? does it crash? what does it do instead?

Comment: returns a value error in the cell when referenced in excel and if a breakpoint is put into the visual studio code it never reaches it

Comment: Show the rest of the function and how you call it.

Comment: the function is called from a cell as in "=WhitenWithBypassCurve(A5:A9, ...........)" In terms of the whole code the problem seems to be in setting the rngsizes() as optional

Comment: I don't see how a double can hold a Nothing value ...

Comment: Are you talking about a double array or just any double value. The only term that seems to have a problem when a value is not included is the rngSizes() term. What would you reccomend